# embedded youtube videos posted by app is visible in app but embedded videos posted from web app shows as strings ionic

Tags: angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework, ngsanitize

i have a div which contains iframe datas such as

```
        <div class="video-container" ng-bind-html="trustedContentSce(value.content)" class="item"></div>
                <p ng-bind-html="value.content"></p>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.trustedContentSce=function(value){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(value)
};
```

and also included following in app.config

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', new  RegExp('^(http[s]?):\/\/(w{3}.)?youtube\.com/.+$')]);
```

I Receive data in value.content as

```
 &lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lGP1YFE5s4M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>
```

and while posting through my app

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fk4BbF7B29w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

which is pretty much same. isn't it?

Here is screen shot of problem i am facing (above video is posted from app and one below is posted from web

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't have an answer but i found a workAround. Before I used Text editor in php but when i use textarea it worked. don't know why ? isn't this:

```
 &lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lGP1YFE5s4M" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen&gt;&lt;/iframe>
```

and this considered same when used ng-bind-html :

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/fk4BbF7B29w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```